# Userform entering data to multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, assets

I followed a guide online which said to said to setup a multi-page within user-form and then the code was supplied but still getting syntax errors and can't seem to work out what wrong.

I want end user to choose which page they want to fill out and then they hit submit and it'll then submit the data into the correct sheet within the workbook.

If user has piece of new kit to register in system they fill out register bit and then hit submit and it puts data into the register sheet, so on and so forth e.g. fill out deploy kit form it put data into the deploy sheet.

the asset number at top of form gets automatically added to each entry.

ignore reporting page going to tackle that at a later date.

I try add code after posting question error popping up

```
Private Sub SB1_Click()

    Dim lrREG As Long, lrB As Long, lrDep As Long, lrDis As Long

    lrREG = Sheets("Register").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Register").Cells(lrREG + 1, "A").Value = TextBox1.Text
    Sheets("Register").Cells(lrREG + 1, "B").Value = TextBox2.Text
    Sheets("Register").Cells(lrREG + 1, "C").Value = TextBox3.Text
    Sheets("Register").Cells(lrREG + 1, "D").Value = TextBox4.Text
    Sheets("Register").Cells(lrREG + 1, "E").Value = TextBox5.Text
    Sheets("Register").Cells(lrREG + 1, "F").Value = TextBox6.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit you question instead of commenting you code, I'v edited the code into your question, please delete your comments.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi I changed the " " marks and now it working fine. I added another question cause I'm trying to run before I can walk but basically added a data sheet which take the Asset ID in column A and then additional info get added to same row but I don't know how to tell user-form look for specific ID number and then use that row

Comment: Thank you for fixing my fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will do it this way, using Range and Declaring Workbook and you always mention the name of the UserForm when you are calling its objects.

```
Private Sub SB1_Click()
'Declare the Variables
Dim lrREG As Long
Dim WrReg as Long
Dim Wk As Workbook

'Assign the Declared Variables
Set Wk = ActiveWorkbook

lrREG = Wk.Sheets("Register").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
WrReg = lrREG + 1

Sheets("Register").Range("A" & wrReg).Value = FormName.TextBox1.Value
Sheets("Register").Range("B" & wrReg).Value = FormName.TextBox2.Value
Sheets("Register").Range("C" & wrReg).Value = FormName.TextBox3.Value
Sheets("Register").Range("D" & wrReg).Value = FormName.TextBox4.Value
Sheets("Register").Range("E" & wrReg).Value = FormName.TextBox5.Value
Sheets("Register").Range("F" & wrReg).Value = FormName.TextBox6.Value


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed the input bit now works a treat thank you.